# Making all items inside a container smaller

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage where all items on the page are inside a container but I would like to make everything smaller by 25%. I have tried:

**Container.CSS**

```
.container{
     transform: scale(0.75);
}
```

But this technique shrinks the entire page making it about 2 inches offset from the top of the screen, and also makes all the items on the page blurry.

*Question. Does anyone know a quick and easy way to do what I want to do, or will I have to individually make every item in the CSS 25% smaller?*

**Thanks**

Comment: I think the best way is resize all one by one in the css.

Comment: I was hoping no one would say that

Comment: Not at all an XY problem, I have shown what I have tried and given the results from that, I have then added a further suggestion to possibilities and then finally asked the question if there is in fact an easier way...

Comment: But why do you want to make everything smaller by 25%? Is there a reason you can't/don't want to just change everything to the right size?

Comment: My browser's settings had it zoomed out to 75% as a default from the start of my development and now ive put it on another pc and realised everything is 25% too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't uploaded any code for us to edit, all I can say is that I would give the main page container or body a width of 75%, and then make every element inside have percentual widths, so they stay responsive.

But as you noted the `transform: scale(0.75);` solution, I conclude you also want the font, borders, etc to shrink. Your best solution is to convert the `px` values to `em` values (generally speaking `16px = 1em`) for those things, and then change the body's font-size to 75%, shrinking everything in the page, because 1em has then become 12px.

Might take some time, but when you're done, your whole page has been made dynamic

Hope this helps

Comment: I didn't upload any code for anyone to edit because this isn't something i'm being 'lazy' about and want other people to do it i just wanted some advice before I started doing it. thanks for your answer, I'll give it a go

Answer (score 0):

If responsive design so easy, all non-mobile friendly sites could be fixed in 1 minute. But it's not that way I'm afraid.

The individual items would need to have percentage widths on them. Using max-width with percentage widths is good too. For example you would have your main container set at 75% and a max-width of whatever the maximum your graphics can take inside. If your items inside have % widths then the one at 25% will always be 25% of whatever size the container is.